# How to use the same command multiple times?

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have a very Basic Question.

For example, I use this command to show the User the last changed time of a Folder.

```
dblc.Content = Directory.GetLastWriteTime(dbfolder);
```

I might have to do this like 3 or 4 times. Should I create a function that I call or should I just copy this a few times?

I wonder what is the better solution to using the same command multiple times.

Thanks

Comment: I have to call them at different times, So first after Starting the Program, then after Pressing a Button etc.

Comment: This question is so hardly depending on many points, that it´s hard to find the one and only answer - if there even exists any. Voting to close as opinion-based.

Comment: Note that in WPF a command is something entirely different. What you are showing here is usually referred to as "statement" or "expression statement": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/statements#expression-statements

Answer (score 1):

If you use it more than once in the same script --> create a local function

```cs
private void Example() {
    // Your code here
}
```

If you use it more than once in different scripts --> create a global static function in another class (eg. Helper)

```cs
public static void Example() {
    // Your code here
}
```

If you use it more than once one after another --> use a loop

```cs
int repetitions = 5;
for (int i = 0; i <= repetitions; i++) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: So creating a funtion, even with this small and easy Task would be the better way to go then just Copy pasting the Method?

Comment: Yep, thats a reasonable way to go about division of code.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is, if the command is simple to understand (such as the one in the example) and the purpose of each use is largely unique the overhead of creating a function/method or property isn't usualy worthwhile.

As a general guide, consider your code from a operation perspective. Ask these questions:

1. Is this activity often repeated?
2. Is it complicated?
3. Does each use share similar purpose?

If you find the answer you answer yes to all three, then putting the implementation in a method, function, property or class is a good idea.

Lastly, the example you give is very understandable of itself. There wouldn't be much value in wrapping that again.

Comment: @KVKConsultancy I suppse it´s the same guy that downvoted the question and the other answer, simplybecause the question in itself is way too broad.